# Convert 'spec' S3 class to new S4 class

Tags: r, class, r-s4, spectrum

In `R` I want to convert (coerce?) an object returned from `stats::spectrum` (class 'spec') into a new S4 class.  The S3 class 'spec' is essentially a list of various information with mixed formats (I've commented the screen output):

```
psd3 <- spectrum(rnorm(1e3), plot=FALSE)
summary(psd3)
#           Length Class  Mode     
# freq      500    -none- numeric  
# spec      500    -none- numeric  
# coh         0    -none- NULL     
# phase       0    -none- NULL     
# kernel      0    -none- NULL     
# df          1    -none- numeric  
# bandwidth   1    -none- numeric  
# n.used      1    -none- numeric  
# orig.n      1    -none- numeric  
# series      1    -none- character
# snames      0    -none- NULL     
# method      1    -none- character
# taper       1    -none- numeric  
# pad         1    -none- numeric  
# detrend     1    -none- logical  
# demean      1    -none- logical 

class(unclass(psd3))
# [1] "list"

is.object(psd3) & !isS4(psd3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Now let's say we define a new, S4 generator for a class named 'specS4', wherein the slot names are the names in the 'spec' object

```
specS4 <- setClass("specS4",
  representation = representation(freq="numeric", spec="numeric", coh="numeric", phase="numeric", kernel="numeric", df="numeric", bandwidth="numeric", n.used="numeric", orig.n="numeric", series="character", snames="character", method="character", taper="numeric", pad="numeric", detrend="logical", demean="logical"), 
  prototype = prototype(coh=numeric(0), phase=numeric(0), kernel=numeric(0), df=Inf, snames="", detrend=FALSE, demean=FALSE)
)
```

and generate a new object from it:

```
psd4 <- specS4()

validObject(psd4)
# [1] TRUE
```

What would be the best way to assign each component of `psd3` to its corresponding slot in `psd4`?  *A complication is that `spectrum` may return `NULL` for a few (known) fields; assigning these values would throw an error in `checkSlotAssignment` (for the representation given).*

A painful solution I have is:

```
nonull.spec <- function(psd){
  stopifnot(inherits(psd, 'spec', FALSE))
  # as.numeric(NULL) --> numeric(0)
  # spec.pgram/.ar both may return NULL for these:
  psd$coh <- as.numeric(psd$coh)
  psd$phase <- as.numeric(psd$phase)
  psd$kernel <- as.numeric(psd$kernel)
  psd$snames <- as.character(psd$snames)
  return(psd)
}

as.specS4 <- function(psd) UseMethod("as.specS4")
as.specS4.spec <- function(psd){
  stopifnot(inherits(psd, 'spec', FALSE))
  ## deal with possible NULLs
  psd <- nonull.spec(psd)
  ## generate specS4 class
  S4spec <- specS4()
  ## (re)assign from 'spec' list
  S4spec@freq <- psd$freq
  S4spec@spec <- psd$spec
  S4spec@coh <- psd$coh
  S4spec@phase <- psd$phase
  S4spec@kernel <- psd$kernel
  S4spec@snames <- psd$snames
  # [more to assign, obviously]
  # 
  # [run a validity check...]
  #
  return(S4spec)
}
```

Which works, even though `as.specS4.spec` is intentionally incomplete.

```
psd4c <- as.specS4(psd3)

validObject(psd4c)
# [1] TRUE
```

Is there a better way to achieve what `as.specS4.spec` does?  This solution seems precarious.

Comment: Because it was so helpful for me, here's Hadley's description of the S4 system: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/S4

Comment: My understanding is that you would need to define 'new' and 'as' S4methods. Building an S4 class involves more than defining a structure and creating an `as.name` function.  At the moment I do not think you have an S4 `as`-method. You need `setMethod` to create an S4 method.

Comment: You're right, but `as` and `setAs` are for S4 classes.  So this works: `setClass('spec',prototype=specS4()); setAs("spec", "specS4", function(from, to){
  new(to,
      freq = from$freq,
      spec = from$spec,
      coh = as.numeric(from$coh),
      phase = as.numeric(from$phase),
      kernel = as.numeric(from$kernel),
      snames = as.character(from$snames))
}); as(psd3, 'specS4')` but as you may notice I still need to manually assign slots. Unless I'm missing something, that doesn't really save me any effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized how simple this actually is. *Doh!*

Match `slotNames` in the 'specS4' object with `names` in the 'spec' object, then assign with `slot` (assumes code in the question has been run):

```
as.specS4.spec <- function(psd){
  stopifnot(inherits(psd, 'spec', FALSE))
  psd <- nonull.spec(psd)
  S4spec <- specS4() 
  spec_slots <- slotNames(S4spec)
  spec_slots <- spec_slots[match(names(psd), spec_slots)]
  for (what in spec_slots){
    slot(S4spec, what) <- as.vector(unlist(psd[what]))
  }
  return(S4spec)
}

psd4c2 <- as.specS4(psd3)

validObject(psd4c2)
# [1] TRUE
> all.equal(psd4c@freq, psd4c2@freq, psd3$freq)
# [1] TRUE
```